# Semi-continuity of the value of contour integral in the Argument principle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

Let $f(z,w)$ be a meromorphic function (in both $z$ and $w$) inside and on some closed contour $\gamma$. Consider

\begin{align}
 N(w):  =   \frac{1}{2\pi i}  \oint \limits_{\gamma} \frac{  \frac{df(z,w)}{dz} }{f(z,w)}   \mathrm{d}z 
\end{align}
 According to [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), the value of $N(w)$ is the difference between the number of zeros and poles of $f$. Since $N(w)$ is an integer number, it cannot be a continuous function of $w$. I was wondering whether $N(w)$ is semi-continuous as a function of $w$?

We can assume $w\in W$, and the function $f(z,w)$ remains meromorphic and has no zeros/poles on $\gamma$ for all the points $w\in W$.

I am new to complex analysis, I greatly appreciate any comment/response.

Comment: I'm not qualified to write the long and interesting answer that this question deserves - I don't know much about complex analysis, and I don't know anything at all about functions of several complex variables - but as there has been no answer yet, I'll note that the main point to make in response is that $N(w)$ is only defined for values of $w$ such that $f(z, w) \ne 0$ for all $z$ on $\gamma$, and these will not usually form a connected set, so there is no reason why $N$ should not be continuous. (I'll delete this stopgap comment when a proper answer appears.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Thanks for your comment. You are right. For this particular question, we can assume that $w$ belongs to a domain where for all points in this domain, $f$ has no zero or pole on $\gamma$. I will add this to the question to make it clear.

Comment: For example, let $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ ($0 \leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi$), and $f(z, w) = z - w$ ($z, w \in \mathbb{C}$). Then $N(w)$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ about $w$. It is defined iff $w$ does not lie on $\gamma$. Its value is $1$ for $w$ inside $\gamma$, and $0$ for $w$ outside $\gamma$. The function $N$ is continuous on the disconnected open set on which it is defined. (Perhaps this would do as an answer? The more elaborate discussion I was anticipating might not be needed, after all.)

Comment: If $f(z,w) \neq 0$ for all $z$ on $\gamma$ and all $w\in W$, then $N(w)$ is continuous on $W$. For $w$ such that $z \mapsto f(z,w)$ has a zero on $\gamma$, under fairly mild assumptions one can interpret the integral as a principal value integral, and then $N(w)$ won't be semicontinuous at such points (a typical situation is that $N(w) = k$ on one side of a curve, $N(w) = k+1$ on the other, and $N(w) = k + \frac{1}{2}$ on the curve).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Your statements make sense. Is there a way to prove the continuity of $N(w)$ for $w\in W$ (under the condition that $f(z,w) \ne 0$)? Since I don't know much about complex analysis, I don't know how to prove the continuity in this case

Comment: By compactness the integrand is uniformly continuous on $\gamma \times \overline{B_r(w)}$ for sufficiently small $r > 0$. Then use the standard estimate (aka ML-inequality).